# Download async with progress bar and status label

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, asynchronous

On my application, when you click the save button, it should download a zip file whilst showing progress and when the download is completed, it should extract the zip file (using DotNetZip lib) with progress.

When I test it, the progress bar shows changes for few seconds, then it freezes for few seconds and goes to last stage of the process (Extracting completed).

This is my code so far:

```
    // Handle nginx save action
    private void saveNginX_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Disable save button
            (sender as Button).Enabled = false;

            // Generate download & save file name
            var downloadLink = new Uri(myNginXConfig.selected_resource.DownloadLink);
            var saveFilename = @"apps\" + Path.GetFileName(downloadLink.AbsolutePath);

            // Check if file already exists
            if (File.Exists(saveFilename))
            {
                // Download completed, proceed to extracting
                NginXDownloadCompleted();
            }
            else
            {
                // Update status
                nginxStatus.Text = "Downloading " + selectNginX.SelectedItem.ToString() + " ...";
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                // Init download
                using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
                {
                    webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(NginXDownloadProgressChangedEvent);
                    webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(NginXDownloadCompletedEvent);
                    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(downloadLink, saveFilename);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Error
            Utils.ShowError("Failed to save - " + ex.Message);

            // Enable save button
            (sender as Button).Enabled = true;
        }
     }

    // Handle nginx download progress changed event
    private void NginXDownloadProgressChangedEvent(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Update the progressbar percentage only when the value is not the same.
        nginxProgress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

        // Calculate download progresss
        var downloadProgress = string.Format("{0} MB / {1} MB",
            (e.BytesReceived / 1024d / 1024d).ToString("0.00"),
            (e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024d / 1024d).ToString("0.00"));

        // Update download progress
        nginxStatus.Text = "Downloading " + downloadProgress + " ...";
    }

    // Handle nginx download complete event
    private void NginXDownloadCompletedEvent(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled != true)
            NginXDownloadCompleted();
    }

    // Handle nginx download complete
    private void NginXDownloadCompleted()
    {
        // Update status
        nginxStatus.Text = "Download completed; extracting ...";
        nginxStatus.Update();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        nginxProgress.Value = 0;

        // Generate download & save file name
        var downloadLink = new Uri(myNginXConfig.selected_resource.DownloadLink);
        var saveFilename = @"apps\" + Path.GetFileName(downloadLink.AbsolutePath);

        // Begin extracting the downloaded zip file
        using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(saveFilename))
        {
            zip.ExtractProgress += new EventHandler<ExtractProgressEventArgs>(NginXExtractProgressEvent);
            zip.ExtractAll("apps", ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
        }

        // Json encode setting and save it
        // File.WriteAllText(@"apps\NginXConfig.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myNginXConfig, Formatting.Indented));
    }

    // Handle nginx extract progress event
    private void NginXExtractProgressEvent(object sender, ExtractProgressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.TotalBytesToTransfer > 0)
            nginxProgress.Value = Convert.ToInt32(100 * e.BytesTransferred / e.TotalBytesToTransfer);

        if (e.EventType == ZipProgressEventType.Extracting_AfterExtractAll)
            NginXExtractCompleted();
    }

    // Handle nginx extract completed event
    private void NginXExtractCompleted()
    {
        // Update status
        nginxStatus.Text = "Extracting completed; generating config ...";
        nginxStatus.Update();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        nginxProgress.Value = 0;
    }
```

the status label text also appears to be doing the same thing. It feels/looks as if the process is not synchronised, it just jumps.

I've tried using `Label.Update()` method, but that doesn't help.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

I want to procedurally report the progress with status updates on the UI as the events are occurring.

Comment: Don't use `Thread.Sleep`.

Comment: I want to display a piece of info and kick start the next step with a small delay, that's why I am using `Thread.Sleep`. If i shouldn't use this, what alternative method can I implement?

Comment: If you are using a high enough version of .Net you can use the async/await features and use Task.Delay instead. If not refactor your code to use a timer to introduce the delay. As soon as you call Thread.Sleep on the UI thread your screen will freeze.

Comment: I am currently using `.NET 4.5`. I think I will change the project to use the new version `6` and give this `async/await` a go.

Comment: Yeah, that async/await is outside my experience unfortunately, but in general I would advise moving all that code that is currently in your button click event . . . move it into a new method, call it X here for simplicity.  Then inside the button click method write a Task or Thread pointed at method X.  Then start it and you'll free up your main thread to focus on UI as it should.  But use async/await also as you planned to.

Comment: How frequently is method NginXDownloadProgressChangedEvent firing?  That will execute entirely dependent on your webClient.  If your network speed is fast enough, it might only be running infrequently, giving the impression of large jumps to the progressbar.  To test this, you might add a line that writes a log entry to track the real progress of the download.  Your Zip extract process, however, appears to be occurring entirely in the UI thread, which will cause the behavior you describe.  If you extract in a thread separate from the UI, you might fix that problem.

Comment: WDS - I plan to move this code into it's own class at some point (after getting it working) and then combine it with async/await to make it work as intended. @Russ - will using task/async/await make the zip extract process run on separate thread other than main?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the NginXDownloadCompleted method. While DownloadFileAsync is asynchronous method, ExtractAll is not, so your code asynchronously download file from internet but then freeze main thread for the time of file extracting.

What you need - is to create separate background thread (using any available options: via Thread class, via ThreadPool, via Tasks) and do entire work for both downloading and extracting in this thread in synchronous way.

Some notes:

- You do not need Thread.Sleep in main thread at all it won't help
- Do not forget to replace asynchronous download in new separate thread to synchronous (DownloadFile instead of DownloadFileAsync)
- Progress events that will trigger in background thread will work in different context, so you cannot directly update UI, instead you need to provoke main thread to do this (easiest way is to use Control.BeginInvoke)